# Accessing this.props.location.pathname within the Route component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

On my SideMenuNavigation component where I have the `<Route>` codes, I need to access the value of `this.props.location.pathname`. Unfortunately, I'm getting `undefined`.

```
class SideNavigation extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.props.location.pathname); // undefined
  }

  render() {
    return(
     <Router>
       <Route exact path="/" component={Dashboard}/>
     </Router>
    )
  }
}


/*   */
```

In my Dashboard component, I can acess `this.props.location.pathname` successfully. Unforunately, I don't need it from this component. I need the value in the `SideMenuNavigation` component.

Answer (score 1):

`location` is one of the props that are injected by Router component. In your case SideNavigation isn't Router component's child (in fact it is a parent). You're might be interested in this question also: [How does react-router pass params to other components via props?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32901538/how-does-react-router-pass-params-to-other-components-via-props)

Comment: I got it working with the use of withRouter and pathless <Route> so `export default withRouter(SideNavigation)` and <Route component={SideNavigation}/> It's fixed! :)